# Update Table using values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a row called `ctcode` in a table called `partnumber` copying values from the row `ctcode` in a table called `families`. My SQL statement however returns and "Unknown Column 'families.parent' in 'where clause'" error.

Here is my SQL Statement

```
UPDATE `partnumber` 
SET `partnumber`.`ctcode`=`families`.`ctcode` 
WHERE `partnumber`.`partnumber`=`families`.`parent`;
```

What is wrong with my statement? Is there any more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can basically join both tables even in `UPDATE` statements,

```
UPDATE `partnumber` a INNER JOIN `families` b
          ON a.`partnumber` = b.`parent`
SET    a.`ctcode`= b.`ctcode`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your SQL Statement generates this error `"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`.`partnumber`= b.`parent SET `a.`ctcode`= b.`ctcode`' at line 1"`

Answer (score 2):

Works in MySQL 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

```
UPDATE `partnumber`, `families`
SET `partnumber`.`ctcode`=`families`.`ctcode` 
WHERE `partnumber`.`partnumber`=`families`.`parent`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
UPDATE partnumber 
SET ctcode = f.ctcode   
FROM partnumber p 
INNER JOIN families f ON p.partnumber = f.parent
```